# using font awesome icons-navbar wont collapse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to using bootstrap,I am trying to add a user icon that should collapse when a user clicks on it. when i try to add `navbar-toggle` to a class the user icon item disappears.If i remove it the icon appears but when i click on the icon it doesn't collapse.
what am i doing wrong? how do i get the icon to "open/collapse"

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse visible-sm" >
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-account" ><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> // i tried adding the class as "navbar-brand pull right navbar-toggle collapsed" but when i do this the user icon disappears
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-account" data-text="Login" data-class="login"> // this part doesn't open
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  


</body>
</html>
```

source: w3schools.com